# What is the optimal way to store data-files for testing using travis-ci + Docker?

Tags: testing, docker, automated-tests, travis-ci

I am trying to set-up the testing of the repository using travis-ci.org and Docker. However, I couldn't find any manuals about what is the politics on memory usage.

To perform a set of tests (`test.sh`) I need a set of input files to run on, which are very big (up to 1 Gb, but average 500 Mb).

One idea is to `wget` directly in `test.sh` script, but for each test-run it would be not efficient to download the input file again and again.
The other idea is to create a separate dockerfile containing the test-files and mount it as a drive, but this would be not nice to push such a big dockerimage in the general register.

Is there a general prescription for such tests?

Comment: i'm really perplexed that Google doesn't find much around this topic? How do people do their tests on real data? Have you found a good way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Travis File Cache](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/)?

You can write your `test.sh` script in a way so that it will only download a test file if it was not available on the local file system yet.

In your `.travis.yml` file, you specify which directories should be cached after a successful build. Travis will automatically restore that directory and files in it at the beginning of the next build. As your `test.sh` script will then notice the file exists already, it will simply skip the download and your build should be a little faster.

Note that how the Travis cache works is that it will create an archive file and put it on some cloud storage where it will need to download it later on as well. However, the assumption is that the network traffic will likely be inside that "cloud" and potentially in the same data center as well. This should still give you some benefits in terms of build time and lower use of resources in your own infrastructure.